# MongoDB Query names ignoring trailing numbers

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

Let's say we have the following documents:

`{ "name": "teST" },
 { "name": "tEst2" },
 { "name": "TEST3333" },
 { "name": "TESTAAAA"}`

Given the string `test` is there a way I can query only the three first records with numbers after the given string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a regex like `/^test[0-9]*$/i`

- `^` -- start of string
- `[0-9]*` -- any number of digits (including 0)
- `$` -- end of string
- `i` -- ignore capitalization

So, your query would look like `{name: {$regex: /^test[0-9]*$/i}}`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/